# Text with shapes in drawable resource

Tags: android, text, resources, drawable, shapes

Can i create text-shape in drawable resource? 
I was googling much but found nothing...
Here is my drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
         <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#QQffQQ"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
         </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:right="59dp" android:left="59dp">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="£22££20"/>
         </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:top="59dp" android:bottom="59dp">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="£20££20"/>
         </shape>
      </item>
      <item>
         <!--text should be here-->
      </item>
   </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot do so. One idea is to set the `Drawable` as the background for a `TextView` and then simply set text in the `TextView`, which will appear above the other layers of your `Drawable`. Of course, this cannot be used for a splash screen, which requires a drawable resource as mentioned by [zyamys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117960/zyamys) in a comment below. An idea for that case is to generate static images with the text you are interested in. This unfortunately does not cover cases where the text is to be dynamic.

Comment: Why not use a TextView? Because perhaps OP wants to use text in a splash screen, which requires a drawable resource, not a layout resource.

Comment: Or they might want to use the drawable with a TransitionDrawable that includes some text so the cross fade transitions the background with some wording. You could switch to an image, but that defeats the use of a drawable layer-list.

Comment: @zyamys What would be your suggestion in the scenario you mentioned above, i.e. text in splash screen which requires drawable resource?

Comment: @user846316 I don't have a good answer. I ended up generating png files with my text.

Comment: @zyamys I also thought of doing the same but localized text in png is a pain... can't create so many images just for splash :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use vector drawable instead (say by converting from svg file).
Then use vector as one of the layers.
**This lets you create a single drawable without any TextViews, so you can easily use it as a windowBackground in your splash screen theme.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="270"
                      android:startColor="#C3DAE0"
                      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splash_text"/>
</layer-list>
```

Where **ic_splash_text** - is a vector drawable with the text.

Not forget to add vectors support if you are4 targeting onto API<21.
For this you have to:

1. Add to your module build.gradle (app-level):

   ```
   android {        
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true.    
   }
   ```
2. Register delegate in a static block of your activity:

   ```
   static {  
       AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);   
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a wonderful answer - you may also need to convert the text to a path within the SVG, as Vector Drawables cannot handle text