# How can I add the app name in a splash screen based on a layer-list?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to create a splash screen containing the app name. How can I add text to a layer-list?

This is my splash screen file at the moment:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical" />
        <item> <!--APP NAME--></item>
    </layer-list>
```

I already tryed to create a png file with the app name but this caused some issues on different screen sizes.

I already tryed to create a png file with the text but it does not work for all screen sizes.

Comment: What does the layer-list that you tried look like? In what way does it not work (what was the result)?

Comment: Apparently there is not a clean way to put text into a layer-list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161959/android-text-in-drawable-layer-list

Comment: I updated the question with some code. It should be a white screen and in the center the app name. I do not know how I can add a text item.

Comment: How is it possible to creare a png that fits for most of the screens? I don not have much experience in those things.

Comment: did you got anything ?

Comment: No, I didn't.  Since now I haven't tried other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vector drawable (`app_logo.xml`) with your text as window background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

Setting theme:

```
<style name="NewSplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

This will work correctly on API level >= 23, you should provide an alternative version of `background_splash` with raster graphics for previous API levels (see @Venky's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image in layer list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

In theme.xml

```
<style name="NewSplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Don't forget to create an image with **App Name**